# can someone explain this filter() function for me?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

```
def only_even(L):

    return list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0,filter(lambda x:type(x) == int or type(x) == float,L)))

a = only_even([1,2,3,46,"String", "noch ein String", 2.0, True, [2,4]])
print(a)
```

why can man write the `filter()` function like this?
the first parameter takes two funktion as arguments

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I strongly recommend learning more Python, and about programming in general. Stack Overflow is meant for specific technical questions, whereas you really need and would benefit most from a back and forth of explanations.

Comment: what kind of questions are preferred by Stackflow?

Answer (score 5):

Each `filter` is taking one predicate (the function determining whether the element is a member or not), but there are two filters. This is equivalent to:

```py
numbers = filter(lambda x: type(x) == int or type(x) == float, L)
return list(filter(lambda x: x%2 == 0, numbers))
```

It is, however, incredibly awful. First of all, `L` should not be heterogenous. If it is, we've probably done something Bad elsewhere in the codebase. Even if that were the case, since we're casting to list afterwards we should just use a list comprehension to begin with.

```py
return [x for x in L if isinstance(x, (int, float)) and  x%2==0]
```

Here I also use `isinstance` to check for either type in one call rather than comparing `type(x)` by equality twice.

Alternatively, you could write this explicitly, which is less terse but more easily readable

```py
evens = []
for candidate in L:
    try:
        if candidate % 2 == 0:
            evens.append(candidate)
    except TypeError:
        # "candidate" is not a number -- ignore it
        pass
return evens
```

However I *must* stress that code like this is the sign of something having gone wrong elsewhere in the code base. Your function should not have to test type before handling the object -- it should be type safe wherever possible, even in Python.

Comment: yeah,agree. the list comprehensiv is here more understandable..but this is a quest of my homework. so lambda must be used here.

Comment: @JasonLu is the crux of the homework using `lambda` expressions, or using `filter`? If the latter, just write an actual function. `def even_predicate(value): return isinstance(value, (int, float)) and value%2==0` then `def only_even(L): return list(filter(even_predicate, L))`

Comment: Unlike the original, you don't filter out `False`.

Comment: unfortunately i must use filter() and lambda xD.
by the way. u gave me two functions. but what if i only want to filter elements that are not `int()` and `float()` in the list. i mean that i only want to pass the list in the parameter

Comment: @StefanPochmann ah that's true, since Python implements `bool` as a subclass of `int`.

Comment: anyway it is quit confusing that the arguments in filter() can just be seperated by `,` and no errors are raised. is it kind of nested function?

Comment: @JasonLu what do you mean? That's the syntax for all function calls in Python. `function_name(arg1, arg2, arg3, ..., argN)`

Comment: @Adam Smith i mean,how python knows that `,filter(lambda x:type(x) == int or type(x) == float,L` is a new seq insead that `filter(lambda x:type(x) == int or type(x) == float`is a zweit argument for the first `filter()`

Comment: @JasonLu parentheses group. `filter(f, seq)`. In this case `seq` is also a `filter(f, seq)`, but that's apparent to Python due to the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter()` method takes two parameters:

function - function that tests if elements of an iterable returns true or false
If `None`, the function defaults to Identity function - which returns false if any elements are false

iterable - iterable which is to be filtered, could be sets, lists, tuples, or containers of any iterators.

The `filter()` method returns iterable.

In your case the function is defined as a lambda which checks if the number is even (`lambda x: x%2==0`). The iterable is filtered against the type, accepting only integers and floats.